# JS file called twice in Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to reduce number of requests by reducing number of JS files on WP site. I successfully combined around 7 javascript files into one (`site.js`). Now, I'm using a plugin which has its own JS file (`pluginA.js`), I want to include (`pluginA.js`) in that site.js. However, if I simply copy pluginA JS content to site.js and then change location to `/files/site.js`, firebug's NET tab shows that site.js is requested/called twice. I presume this is due to `wp_enqueue_script`.

How can I make it not call site.js second time but just look into already loaded site.js?
Maybe there's alternative to `wp_enqueue_script`?

Plugin's php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testplugin_scripts');
    function testplugin_scripts() {
        /*global $testplugin_version; */
            $default_selector = 'li:has(ul) > a';
            $default_selector_leaf = 'li li li:not(:has(ul)) > a';
       wp_enqueue_scripts('test-plugin', site_url('/files/site.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), $testplugin_version);
            $params = array(
                    'selector' => apply_filters('testplugin_selector', $default_selector),
                    'selector_leaf' => apply_filters('testplugin_selector_leaf', $default_selector_leaf)
            );
            wp_localize_script('test-plugin', 'testplugin_params', $params);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried de-registering the previous script?

Answer (score 0):

If the load time difference is marginal between having it included separately or having it in your site.js file, then I would leave the plugin.js alone. The only reason for that is that if you keep on adding to your site.js and then download a new version of the plugin, you might run into difficulties. To compensate, I would go with a JS compressor that can significantly reduce the size of your site.js thus possibly providing a greater benefit than with simply reducing the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, eventually I'll compress the JS. Also, I prefer adding that plugins JS into site.js because I'm going to integrate that plugin directly into my theme and that will be easier in case I need to migrate. Also, I'm not worried about plugin's update. By the way, I have minified and normal version of site.js where the latter has proper comments so that I can clearly identify what is what. I just don't know how to make it not call for site.js second time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution ( a bit hacky ): Do not include `site.js` and therefore the script will only be called once (from the plugin)

Comment: How about other way around? so that plugin doesn't call second time because site.js is already loaded (it's in header).